# Show and enable reboot text and button after WiX bootstrapper chain

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, wix3.8

Basically, I want to allow the user to restart his/her machine easily after the setup chain is complete. Just using `<ExitCode ...` after the last chain element is no option for me, because I do not want to force the user to restart and my last element is a `MsiPackage`, I simply want to give the user the **option** to restart, very quick.

Of course I could implement this feature in the Msi itself, but I also found this in a theme file of the bootstrapper:

```
<Page Name="Success">
    <Text X="186"
                Y="80"
                Width="-11"
                Height="30"
                FontId="2"
                DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.SuccessHeader)</Text>
    <Button Name="LaunchButton"
                    X="-91"
                    Y="-11"
                    Width="75"
                    Height="23"
                    TabStop="yes"
                    FontId="0"
                    HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.SuccessLaunchButton)</Button>
    <Text Name="SuccessRestartText"
                X="186"
                Y="-51"
                Width="-11"
                Height="32"
                FontId="3"
                DisablePrefix="yes"
                HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.SuccessRestartText)</Text>
    <Button Name="SuccessRestartButton"
                    X="-116"
                    Y="-11"
                    Width="100"
                    Height="23"
                    TabStop="yes"
                    FontId="0"
                    HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.SuccessRestartButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="SuccessCancelButton"
                    X="-11"
                    Y="-11"
                    Width="100"
                    Height="23"
                    TabStop="yes"
                    FontId="0">#(loc.SuccessCloseButton)</Button>
</Page>
```

You see, there is a RestartText and RestartButton. When removing `HideWhenDisabled` I could see the elements after the setup, but they are still disabled obviously.

While in the wxs file is a `SupressRepair` tag in the `bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication` node to disable and hide the repair button and function, there even must be any option to enable the reboot text, button and function.

I could not determine where to set this. So, how can I enable the reboot text and button after the setup in the bootstrapp application.

Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, my solution was very easy and could be detected by myself when trying to reboot after MSI install:

When telling the MSI package to reboot after successful install by applying

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

to my wxs file of my MSI project it will not cause the MSI to restart after the setup in the setup chain. Instead of that it will give the bootstrapper any return code so it enables my reboot text and button on the end of the whole setup chain.

I did not expect the bootstrapper is so intelligent. Nice!